# Order-dependant multi-row update in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to Update the Row based on input value

Example : In my Table data like this

```
 **LOTNUMBER QUANTITY** 
    0000001      30
    0000002      30
    0000003      20
    0000004      20
    0000005      10
```

Input Value is **-20** then

I need to fetch latest lot number and update the Lot number `0000005 to 0` and `0000004 to 10`

Then the Output will be

```
**LOTNUMBER  QUANTITY**
    0000001      30
    0000002      30
    0000003      20
    0000004      10
    0000005      0
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind this? How do you infer this behavior from an input like -20?

Comment: @Mureinik think of the table like a stack of resources, the -20 request depleted the "5" slot and took the remainder from the "4' slot.

Comment: lot number generated based on stuffing quantity,total quantity is 90 its split based on stuffing quantity.now i need to minus the value based on stuffing quantity each row

Answer (score 1):

You can combine window functions, CTEs and correlated updates to achieve this, it's ugly and possibly horribly inefficient.  I'm no Oracle expert.

```
update data u set quantity=( 
  with d as 
     ( 
     select lotnumber as l ,  greatest(0,quantity - greatest (0,
     20
     + quantity - sum(quantity) over (order by lotnumber desc))) as v 
     from data
     )  
  select v from d where u.lotnumber=d.l 
);
```

that "20" in the middle is your input value

fiddle here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cce2a